# how to see images of MNIST in tensorflow2

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I am trying to learn TensorFlow2. I have some questions. it would be nice even you introduce a tutorial to find these answers or just please give me answers directly. I am trying to learn , it is not home work or project.

I downloaded MNIST data set from TensorFlowdatasets.

```
Data=tfds.load('mnist')
```

Then I spited train and test

```
test=Data['test']
train=Data['train']
```

Now I wanna access to first picture of train.

1- how I can do that?  why `train[0,0,0]` does not work? how I can split image and label? how I can plot `train[0,0,0]`?

Answer (score 0):

Use matplotlib.pyplot imshow:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for i in range(36): # Plot 36 images
    plt.subplot(6,6,i+1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(x_train[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary) 
    plt.xlabel(y_train[i)    
plt.show()
```

Note: I downloaded MNIST from Keras, but basically it should be the same thing.

Comment: how did you split x_train and y_train in the data set train?

Comment: You can use sklearn's: 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

Comment: Also from Keras library it already splits into train and test

Comment: but is it help for splitting image and label in the train?

Comment: I am talking about splitting image and label of train